# Automate vanila Chrome

Tags: javascript, automation, chromium

I want to send JavaScript code to execute in a Chrome session without Selenium. I mean that I open the browser, connect to the browser process or session and "hijack" it so to say, in a way that I can execute JS code and navigate through pages, open new ones, etc.

Can it be done with just pure, "vanila" Chrome?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without more details. Why do you need *vanilla* chrome? What is your use case? The only alternative to Selenium that I know of is [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer)

Comment: @SamuelMartineau since many sites nowadays can distinguish if you're using selenium or not. Same goes to puppeteer. People always ask questions on stackoverflow/github "How can I prevent my Selenium from being detected?" and such, but I suppose it's in the code of the driver itself which makes it detectable. So, to get out of this cat and mouse game, I would like to implement the driver myself. Everyone should do that, so that no one is under the control of driver creators, expecially when they're doing something borderline malicious.